# Browserlist config do not include Map polyfill

Tags: vue.js, polyfills, babel-polyfill

As I understand Browserlist tool is automatically adds needed polyfills if older browser support required. I'm trying to run ES6 js code in old Android Chrome Webview v.30 but got error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined", source: http://localhost/js/chunk-vendors.ed003893.js`

My .browserslistrc set to:

`Chrome > 20`

Running `npx browserslist` shows that in includes chrome from 21 version and above. But after building production and running in WebView I got the same error that `Map is not defined`. Do I need manually add ES6 polyfill?

P.s. I'm using Vuejs 2

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by adding es.map polyfill to babel.config.js file:

````
  presets: [
    ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset', {
      polyfills: [
        'es.map',
      ],
    }],
  ],
}```
````